# Installing VirtualBox on Debian 12 Bookworm With Errors

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, secure-boot, kernel-module

I have a Clevo PD70SND-G, fresh from China. Installed Debian 12 Bookworm. I am attempting to install, and use, VirtualBox. I have data on a VirtualBox machine that I need access to.

I have attempted to install from the official Debian repository, after adding to the /etc/apt/sources.list, and get dependency errors (see below). So, I went to VirtualBox.org and downloaded their package file for Debian 12, and installed it. The VirtualBox Manager appears to run fine, but when I attempt to start a machine, I get errors about a kernel driver not installed (see below). And errors with "unsigned" kernel modules. The MOK signature files were created while getting the NVIDIA GPU to work with Secure Boot activated.

The machine is Ubuntu 22.04, created on a Windows 10 host.

Please help.

About the system:

```
Info Center -> About this System:

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.5 KDE
Frameworks Version: 5.103.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.1.0-17-amd64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 32 × Intel® Core™ i9-14900HX
Memory: 62.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: Notebook
Product Name: > PD5x_7xSNC_SND_SNE
System Version: Not Applicable
```

```
$ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          user@Computer-Name 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------------------- 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: PD5x_7xSNC_SND_SNE 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 7 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2984 (dpkg) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.27.5 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin 
  `Y$$                        Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
   `Y$$.                      Icons: [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3] 
     `$$b.                    Terminal: konsole 
       `Y$$b.                 CPU: Intel i9-14900HX (32) @ 2.200GHz 
          `"Y$b._             GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile 
              `"""            GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics 
                              Memory: 2373MiB / 64000MiB
```

Attempting to install VirtualBox from official Debian 12 repositories:

```
$ sudo apt install fasttrack-archive-keyring
Append to /etc/apt/sources.list:
    deb https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ bullseye-fasttrack main contrib 
    deb https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ bullseye-backports-staging main contrib

$ sudo apt update
```

```
$ aptitude search virtualbox
p   boinc-virtualbox                                     - metapackage for virtualbox-savvy projects                     
p   virtualbox                                           - x86 virtualization solution - base binaries                   
p   virtualbox-dbgsym                                    - debug symbols for virtualbox                                  
p   virtualbox-dkms                                      - x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms  
p   virtualbox-ext-pack                                  - extra capabilities for VirtualBox, downloader.                
p   virtualbox-guest-additions-iso                       - guest additions iso image for VirtualBox                      
v   virtualbox-guest-modules                             -                                                               
p   virtualbox-guest-utils                               - x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities         
p   virtualbox-guest-utils-dbgsym                        - debug symbols for virtualbox-guest-utils                      
p   virtualbox-guest-x11                                 - x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities             
p   virtualbox-guest-x11-dbgsym                          - debug symbols for virtualbox-guest-x11                        
v   virtualbox-modules                                   -                                                               
p   virtualbox-qt                                        - x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface         
p   virtualbox-qt-dbgsym                                 - debug symbols for virtualbox-qt                               
p   virtualbox-source                                    - x86 virtualization solution - kernel module source
```

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox : Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
              Depends: python3.9 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgsoap-2.8.104 but it is not installable
              Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libvpx6 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 7.0.12-dfsg-1~fto11+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Attempting to install VirtualBox from a downloaded repository file:

```
$ sudo apt install .../virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-7.0' instead of '.../virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm_amd64.deb'
Recommended packages:
  linux-image
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualbox-7.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/92.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 218 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 .../virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm_amd64.deb virtualbox-7.0 amd64 7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm [92.4 MB]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-7.0.
(Reading database ... 343483 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm) ...
Setting up virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Unable to sign vboxdrv.ko.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1) ...
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '.../virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Error message logged in the Notification Center:

```
VM Name: Ubuntu 22.04

The virtual machine 'Ubuntu 22.04' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
Component:
MachineWrap
Interface:
IMachine {300763af-5d6b-46e6-aa96-273eac15538a}
```

Error message in pop-up window:

```
VirtualBox - Error in suplibOsInit

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
‘/sbin/vboxconfig’
as root.

If you system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: sublibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

Results of running the command given:

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig 
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services. 
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services. 
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules. 
vboxdrv.sh: Signing VirtualBox kernel modules. 
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Unable to sign vboxdrv.ko. 
 
There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run 
  /sbin/vboxconfig 
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the 
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load 
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Script: sign-virtualbox

```
#!/bin/bash
for modfile in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/*.ko; do
        echo "Signing $modfile"
        /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file sha256 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der "$modfile"
#       /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der "$modfile"
done
```

As you can see, there is no `vboxpci` module:

```
$ sudo KBUILD_SIGN_PIN=[passcode] sign-virtualbox 
Signing /lib/modules/6.1.0-18-amd64/misc/vboxdrv.ko 
Signing /lib/modules/6.1.0-18-amd64/misc/vboxnetadp.ko 
Signing /lib/modules/6.1.0-18-amd64/misc/vboxnetflt.ko
```

Additional info:

```
$ sudo modinfo vboxdrv 
filename:       /lib/modules/6.1.0-18-amd64/misc/vboxdrv.ko 
version:        7.0.14 r161095 (0x00330004) 
license:        GPL 
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver 
author:         Oracle and/or its affiliates 
srcversion:     152A8CB5D422DE621E72BD6 
depends:         
retpoline:      Y 
name:           vboxdrv 
vermagic:       6.1.0-18-amd64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions  
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)

$ sudo modinfo vboxnetadp 
filename:       /lib/modules/6.1.0-18-amd64/misc/vboxnetadp.ko 
version:        7.0.14 r161095 ((0xA2CDe001U)) 
license:        GPL 
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Network Adapter Driver 
author:         Oracle and/or its affiliates 
srcversion:     DE548A71E9FEE840BC241DC 
depends:        vboxdrv 
retpoline:      Y 
name:           vboxnetadp 
vermagic:       6.1.0-18-amd64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions  
 
$ sudo modinfo vboxnetflt 
filename:       /lib/modules/6.1.0-18-amd64/misc/vboxnetflt.ko 
version:        7.0.14 r161095 ((0xA2CDe001U)) 
license:        GPL 
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Network Filter Driver 
author:         Oracle and/or its affiliates 
srcversion:     5B4916269D291622038DB48 
depends:        vboxdrv 
retpoline:      Y 
name:           vboxnetflt 
vermagic:       6.1.0-18-amd64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: I would contact the computer manufacturer to:  (a) ensure compatibility with Debian, and then (b) how to update the kernel (or whether they suggest a BIOS (UEFI) update.

Comment: They had an option of having Ubuntu preinstalled. Unfortunately, it was a bare-bones system, I purchased the SSD's separately and installed them myself. So for OS installation, I'm on my own. Everything is working perfectly with Debian, except VirtualBox. It is also a relatively new model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my research, I found a script, `/sbin/rcvboxdrv`, to start the kernel modules was created during the install. This is actually a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh`.
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-linux-prereq

I entered the command:

```
$ sudo rcvboxdrv setup
```

Among the output was an error message indicating failure at signing the `vboxdrv` module:

```
...
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Unable to sign vboxdrv.ko.
```

(Very helpful, Oracle!)

I then analyzed the script (vboxdrv.sh) and found the line (805) where error message was thrown, was masking the actural error output of the command by piping it to null. I removed this and the resulting messages (Sorry, I don't have a copy of the actual output, I was too happy to have found the solution.) informed me it was lacking the passcode!

The Fix:
Remove `2>/dev/null` fromm line 805 of `vboxdrv.sh`, and re-run the script:

```
802   # Sign modules.
803   for i in $MODULE_LIST; do
804       "$SIGN_TOOL" "$sig_hashalgo" "$DEB_PRIV_KEY" "$DEB_PUB_KEY" \
805           /lib/modules/"$KERN_VER"/misc/"$i".ko 2>/dev/null || failure "Unable to sign $i.ko"
806   done
```

```
$ sudo KBUILD_SIGN_PIN=[passcode] rcvboxdrv setup
```

Thank you for your time.